# Delphi Firemonkey 3D cube faces

Tags: delphi, 3d, firemonkey, cube

Is possibile to show 6 diffents faces/images in a firemonkey 3d cube texture?
The TLightMaterialSource default apply the same image on all cube faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the FMX.MaterialSources.TTextureMaterialSource.Texture is a TBitMap you can't accomplish what you want in this way. Also looking at the TCube methods, you can't do this without writing your own custom class, which implements the behavior you want.

Take a look at this - http://wiki.freepascal.org/OpenGL_Tutorial#Textures